# Converting Excel Document to PDF Using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, export, interop

I am unable to successfully convert xls and xlsx documents to pdf on the server while using "specific user" identity in DCOM settings for Microsoft Excel Application while using the "ExportAsFixedFormat" method.

My solution also involves converting word documents to pdf and that part of the solution works when I set the identity to "specific user" for Microsoft Word. I should add that the conversion from excel to pdf does work when using "interactive user" identity, however, on Microsoft's website it is stated that the interactive user will only work if there is a user currently logged in. I need the solution to work regardless, which, from what I've read, is accomplished through using "specific user" identity, however, it only works with Microsoft Word and not Microsoft Excel. When the ExportAsFixedFormat is called, the program hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Hello Alex! Could you please update your question with an example of your attempt to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Impurity. As stated, I've only tried using the specified user identity in DCOM settings for Microsoft Excel Application, which results in the program hanging at the ExportAsFixedFormat method. The method works when using interactive user identity but that requires a user to be logged in at all times, which is counterproductive to the purpose of the application.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that the Excel Interop uses the default printer on the server for the ExportAsFixedFormat method. Once I set the default printer to Microsoft XPS Document Writer, it worked fine.

Comment: this isn't working for me. still hangs indefinitely